# Virus that disables keyboard and doesn't allow me to open drives?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, virus, malware, safe-mode

I am now typing from a virtual keyboard. Minutes ago I downloaded a program called Downlite, subsequently, my keyboard, both native [notebook] and external. Mouse buttons don't do their jobs, when I click on a drive, it just shows me statistics of disk space, but doesn't open. All settings are OK - open with dbl click in folder settings, etc.

I am afraid to reset my computer, what if it requires a keyboard entry? Should I call a repair service or try to delete it myself? Thanks

Comment: uninstall the application if you believe it to be the reason this happen.

Comment: Sounds more like a stuck Alt-key than a virus, but if it is malware, it will not interfere with the keyboard during boot. There is no risk in rebooting. In fact, that is what you should do.

Comment: Could be Sticky Keys?